# Parse Ksop Response - Android

Tags: android, ksoap

How should iparse the following ksoap web service response.
        (I am new to this part in android).

This is response obtained from my ksop response to web service. 
I am reunning this on android 4.1 device.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetNearestStationsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetNearestStationsResult>
        <StationsCloseBy xmlns="">
          <Station Station_id="332"
                    Station_Name="דוד המלך 30"
                    Eng_Station_Name="30 David Hamellech St."
                    Description="דוד המלך 30 מול הרבנות בשדרה"
                    Eng_Address="David ha-Melekh 30 opposite the Rabbinate"
                    Latitude="32.080000"
                    Longitude="34.785400"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="61"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="5"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="15"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="331"
                    Station_Name="כיכר רבין"
                    Eng_Station_Name="Rabin Square"
                    Description="כיכר רבין  מול אבן גבירול 76 -תחנה עירייה"
                    Eng_Address="Kikar Rabin, opposite Ibn Gabirol 76 - municipality station"
                    Latitude="32.081000"
                    Longitude="34.781100"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="360"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="12"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="16"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="333"
                    Station_Name="ויצמן 15-איכילוב"
                    Eng_Station_Name="15 weizman st. Ichilov Hospital"
                    Description="ויצמן 15 איכילוב במדרכה מול בית החולים"
                    Eng_Address="Weizman 11 - Hospital"
                    Latitude="32.081100"
                    Longitude="34.788800"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="391"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="6"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="14"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="345"
                    Station_Name="ויצמן 1 -  בית המשפט"
                    Eng_Station_Name="1 Weizman St. - Court Justice Hall"
                    Description="ויצמן 1 בית המשפט"
                    Eng_Address="Weizman 1 - Court Justice Hall"
                    Latitude="32.077200"
                    Longitude="34.788400"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="476"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="4"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="24"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="342"
                    Station_Name="שאול המלך 21 קאמרי"
                    Eng_Station_Name="21 Sauol Hamelekh- Hakameri"
                    Description="שאול המלך 21 קאמרי -במדרכה מימין למדרגות כניסה מערבית"
                    Eng_Address="Shaul ha-Melekh 21 Hakameri - on the sidewalk to the right of the west entrance stairs"
                    Latitude="32.075900"
                    Longitude="34.785100"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="478"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="8"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="12"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="381"
                    Station_Name="פרישמן 77"
                    Eng_Station_Name="77 Frishman St."
                    Description="פרישמן 77-שדרות חן"
                    Eng_Address="77 Frishman St."
                    Latitude="32.079500"
                    Longitude="34.779700"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="488"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="10"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="10"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="323"
                    Station_Name="תשח 2"
                    Eng_Station_Name="2 Tashah St."
                    Description="תשח 2 במדרכה"
                    Eng_Address="Tashakh 2 on the sidewalk"
                    Latitude="32.084700"
                    Longitude="34.786700"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="530"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="6"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="14"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="324"
                    Station_Name="אבן גבירול 106 -בית הדואר"
                    Eng_Station_Name="106 Ibn Gvirol St. - Post Office"
                    Description="אבן גבירול 106 - בית הדואר במדרכה"
                    Eng_Address="Ibn Gabirol 106 - Post Office, on the sidewalk"
                    Latitude="32.084300"
                    Longitude="34.781600"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="546"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="9"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="8"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="346"
                    Station_Name="אבן גבירול 28"
                    Eng_Station_Name="28 Ibn Gabirol St."
                    Description="אבן גבירול 28 לונדון מיניסטור מאחורי ספסל ארוך דרום לכניסה"
                    Eng_Address="Ibn Gabirol 28, London Ministore behind the long bench south of the entrance"
                    Latitude="32.075000"
                    Longitude="34.781800"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="642"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="12"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="8"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
          <Station Station_id="344"
                    Station_Name="נצח ישראל 4 פינת מסריק"
                    Eng_Station_Name="4 Netsakh Yisrael St./ Masaryk"
                    Description="נצח ישראל 4 פינת מסריק - תחנה בחניה בכביש "
                    Eng_Address="Netsakh Yisrael 4 corner of Masaryk - station at the roadside parking"
                    Latitude="32.077900"
                    Longitude="34.778300"
                    DistanceFromStationInMeters="665"
                    Timestamp="2013-01-30T11:05:03.320"
                    NumOfAvailableBikes="8"
                    NumOfAvailableDocks="12"
                    IsActive="1"
                    Station_picture=""
                    Station_Phone="*6070"
                    Telefax="" />
        </StationsCloseBy>
      </GetNearestStationsResult>
    </GetNearestStationsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Assumging:
envelope.bodyIn is Valid
Note1 -

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
int propertyCount = response.getPropertyCount();
String pro = response.getPropertyAsString(0);

Running the code above gives:
propertyCount=1
pro = 
anyType{StationsCloseBy=anyType{Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; Station=anyType{}; }; }

Note2 - ksoap response was chopped (i have removed Additional Stations tags since it does not make any difference, it caontians same fields with different data)

    Any help will be appreciated!
    Thanks!
```

Comment: i need only to get an idea of how to do that correctly. Of course do not expect that someone will code it

Comment: do u get the xml as response ?

Comment: Yes. The one that attached to the question. i have also tried to that with implementing KvmSerializable interefce but this is also did not work. Actually for my opinion the documentation for ksop is un sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this piece of my code will help you to find out how to do it, is in Spanish, I am sorry about the Spanish.

This code only retrieves properties from an XML but for attributes is quite the same.

Good luck!

public static ListaDocumentosPentsFirmante RetrieveFromSoap(SoapObject soap){

```
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) soap.getProperty("getListaPendientesFirmanteResponse");
    ListaDocumentosPentsFirmante pagina_doc =  new ListaDocumentosPentsFirmante();
    ArrayList<DocumentoBandejaFirmanteBean> lista_doc= new  ArrayList<DocumentoBandejaFirmanteBean>();
    /* Parsing every doc entry*/
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getPropertyCount(); i++){

        Object property = root.getProperty(i);
        if(property instanceof SoapObject){
            SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;

            DocumentoBandejaFirmanteBean doc= new DocumentoBandejaFirmanteBean();
            //En caso de no existis?
            if (category_list.hasProperty("codigoDocumento"))
                doc.setCodigoDocumento(Long.parseLong(category_list.getProperty("codigoDocumento").toString()));
            if (category_list.hasProperty("nombreDocumento"))
                doc.setNombreDocumento(category_list.getProperty("nombreDocumento").toString());
            if (category_list.hasProperty("nombreSolicitante"))
                doc.setNombreSolicitante(category_list.getProperty("nombreSolicitante").toString());
            if (category_list.hasProperty("revisado"))
                doc.setRevisado(Boolean.valueOf(category_list.getProperty("revisado").toString()));
            if (category_list.hasProperty("clasificado"))
                doc.setClasificado(Boolean.valueOf( category_list.getProperty("clasificado").toString()));
            if (category_list.hasProperty("tieneAnexos"))
                doc.setTieneAnexos(Boolean.valueOf( category_list.getProperty("tieneAnexos").toString()));
            if (category_list.hasProperty("nombreTipoDocumento"))
                doc.setNombreTipoDocumento(category_list.getProperty("nombreTipoDocumento").toString());
            if (category_list.hasProperty("nombreUnidadAdministrativa"))
                doc.setNombreUnidadAdministrativa(category_list.getProperty("nombreUnidadAdministrativa").toString());
            if (category_list.hasProperty("prioridad"))
                doc.setPrioridad(Integer.parseInt(category_list.getProperty("prioridad").toString()));
            //Date mdFechaAlta = DateFormat.parse(category_doc.getProperty("CATEGORY").toString());
            lista_doc.add(doc);
        }               
    }
    pagina_doc.setDocumentos(lista_doc);
    pagina_doc.setPaginaActual(Integer.parseInt(root.getProperty("paginaActual").toString()));
    pagina_doc.setTotalDocumentos(Integer.parseInt(root.getProperty("totalDocumentos").toString()));
    pagina_doc.setTotalPaginas(Integer.parseInt(root.getProperty("totalPaginas").toString()));

    return pagina_doc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String methodName = "method_name";
String newSoapAction = "initail Url" + methodName;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("your namespace", methodName);    

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        androidHttpTransport
        .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;      
        androidHttpTransport.call(newSoapAction, envelope);         

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(androidHttpTransport.responseDump.getBytes());
```

You will get respponse in Inputstream
For further check [Check this](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-development-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks. i prefer to work with the built in methods like getProperty or getAttribute